# Open Page in New Tab Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, url, tabs

I can't figure out how to open a new tab using JavaScript. I went through related questions but nothing worked for me. I want the browser to open a new tab when someone clicks on the link (example.com) below. What code should I add and where should I place that code?

My html code is here -

```
<section id="work-grid" class="site-inner">
<div class="work-item" data-groups='["all", "webdesign"]' data-url="http://example.com">
<figure class="image-container"><img src="images/work/web-one.jpg" /></figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the target attribute which specifies where to open the linked document,

```
<a href="http://example.com" target="_blank">Example</a>
```

or in javascript,

```
function myFunction() {
    // Open the link in new browser window.
    window.open("http://example.com");
}
```

Comment: You can specify `"_blank"` as the second parameter of the `window.open` _To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special value _blank for strWindowName._ - from the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open)

Answer (score 0):

I can't see  element from code HTML.
and `data-groups='["all", "webdesign"]' data-url="http://example.com"` from #work-item using for?

From HTML Code.

```
<section id="work-grid" class="site-inner">
<div class="work-item">
<figure class="image-container"><img src="images/work/web-one.jpg" onclick="openNewTabLink('example.com')"/></figure>
</div>
```

From Javascript Code.

```
function openNewTabLink(link){window.open(link,'_blank');}
```