# Can't Open Page in New Tab Using Javascript

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, javascript, url, tabs

I can't figure out how to open a new tab using JavaScript. I went through related questions but nothing worked for me. I want the browser to open a new tab when someone clicks on the link (example.com) below. What code should I add and where should I place that code?

My html code is here -

```
<section id="work-grid" class="site-inner">
<div class="work-item" data-groups='["all", "webdesign"]' data-url="http://example.com">
<figure class="image-container"><img src="images/work/web-one.jpg" /></figure>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You don't have an `a` link?

Comment: I am new to web development. The code target="_blank" doesn't work here.

Comment: I know you're new. Start off with the basics and learn how to create a hyperlink.

Comment: You shouldn't do this anyway. The **user** should choose whether links are opened in a new tab, the exsting tab or a new browser instance.

Comment: I agree but this is a little different scenario. Explaining it would be difficult. How do I accomplish it?

Comment: I would consider using JQuery to find by data attribute. Then, assign an event via `on` ... This way, it can be manipulated in the DOM and not use HTML `a` tag

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open Page in New Tab Using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25663805/open-page-in-new-tab-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute `newtab` on the `a` element.

Code for driver for `newtab` `a` attribute:

```
(()=>{document.getElementsByTagName("a").map((e)=>{if(e.newtab==="newtab"){e.target="_blank";e.rel="noopener noreferrer";}return e;});})();
```

Beautified version without an anonymous function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName
(
  "a"
).map
(
  (e) =>
  {
    if (e.newtab === "newtab") {
      e.target = "_blank";
      e.rel = "noopener noreferrer";
    }
    return e;
  }
);
```

> You can only put the compressed version on your page due to uncompressed-code checking.